# How to fixed Crawled (403) forbbiden in scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'https://www.irrawaddy.com/category/business/feed'
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse, meta={'original_url': url})

def parse(self, response):
    try:
        original_url = response.meta.get('original_url')
        final_url = response.url
        print(f"{response.status}")

        if response.status == 200:
            print(f"Original URL: {original_url}, Final URL: {final_url}")
```

```
2024-03-27 14:31:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-03-27 14:31:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-03-27 14:31:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6030
2024-03-27 14:31:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.irrawaddy.com/category/business/feed> (referer: None)
2024-03-27 14:31:30 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.irrawaddy.com/category/business/feed>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2024-03-27 14:31:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you need to add a valid `User-Agent` header, and also check if you are being rate limited by your Public IP Adddress